# Cannot read notification which contains SpannableString instead of regular String

Tags: android, string, android-notifications, spannablestring

**Situation:**

I have code that is reading the text of a notification

```
String notificationText = sbn.getNotification().extras.getString("android.text");
```

and it causes the following error when a notification with special characters is read:

```
Key android.text expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableString.  
The default value <null> was returned. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The particular text that caused this error was a notification from com.whatsapp with the text: "**bold text** regular text"

Note that some characters are in bold. (no exception is thrown without the bold).

**Question:**

Is there a way for me to get this text as a string?

*I have already unsuccessfully tried:*

- *Casting it to a string.*
- *Looking for a different method other than getString to get the text
  from extras*
- *Adding a " " to the end of the string*
- *Checking if the function is returning a SpannableString with
  'instanceof', then casting it to a SpannableString*

Comment: The bad cast is happening in the `getString()` call, so trying to check the type after that won't work. Use `get("android.text")` instead, then check.

Comment: Now that I think about it further, if you handle it everywhere as a `CharSequence` instead of a `String`, you can just do `getCharSequence()`, and not have to do the check. If you ever do need a flat `String`, simply call `toString()` on it.

Comment: I have tried changing the line to: String notificationText = sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString(); but it still shows the same error. However, String notificationText = sbn.getNotification().extras.get("android.text").toString(); does appear to work

Comment: Yep. I have checked it a bit more. Works fine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case struggled almost 3 hrs

```
String.valueOf(sbn.getNotification().extras.get("android.text"));
```

worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
sbn.notification.extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT)**.toString()**
```

this will work 100 %